# Proving that product of two Cauchy sequences is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Given that $x_n$ and $y_n$ are Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R} $, prove that $x_n y_n$ is Cauchy without the use of the Cauchy theorem stating that Cauchy $\Rightarrow$ convergence.

Attempt: Without that condition on not been able to use the theorem, the question becomes trivial.  Instead:

For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n,m \geq N, -\frac{\epsilon}{2} \leq x_n - x_m \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and similar statment for $y_n$. Multiply the above by $y_n$ and the equivalent statement for $y_n$ by $x_m$.  Then add these together.  The result is: $$|x_ny_n - x_my_m| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}(x_m + y_n)$$  I have proved in a previous question that $x_n + y_n$ is Cauchy so could I apply that here and say for $n,m \geq N$, $x_n + y_n$ is Cauchy and hence convergent so tends to a finite limit for $n,m \geq N$.  This would mean my upper bound is a multiple of $\epsilon$ and since $\epsilon$ is arbritarily small, so is this upper bound. Hence Cauchy.

I don't think this would warrant a full proof in any case since by multiplying by $x_m$ and $y_n$, I am assuming they are positive so as to not reverse the inequality signs.  Nonetheless, I would appreciate some feedback on what I have done.

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, see my comment at the bottom of the post

Comment: Just deleted my comment. I realized what you had done.

Comment: You can show that $x_n,y_n$ are bounded without using the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. And you can obtain the same estimate by bounding $x_n y_n - x_m y_m = x_n y_n - x_m y_n + x_m y_n - x_m y_m$ directly.

Comment: That is an interesting approach that works, but since you were told to not use the fact that Cauchy implies convergence, I would find a different approach.

Comment: It does not use that fact that Cauchy implies convergence. To see this, choose $N$ such that $p,q\geq N \Rightarrow |x_p - x_q|<1$. Then clearly $\forall n, |x_n| < 1 + sup (|x_1|, ... , |x_N|)$

Comment: @copper.hat I think you were correct about me assuming that $x_n$ and $y_n$ are nonnegative. Your words 'I realized what you had done' makes me think what I did was in fact okay?  Could you explain if this is the case?

Comment: @ferson2020 So my method is good and makes sense for what I have done?

Comment: @CAF: Yes, what you had done is correct. You would still need to prove the result for the other cases. And you don't need to rely on convergence of the sequences, just boundedness...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HINT: You can make the basic idea work by arranging matters a bit differently. Start with

$$x_ny_n-x_my_m=(x_ny_n-x_ny_m)+(x_ny_m-x_my_m)\;,$$

supply and manipulate absolute values appropriately, and use the fact that a Cauchy sequence is bounded. (Note that boundedness can be proved easily without actually showing convergence.)

Comment: What I have done is the following:  The goal is to see that for all $\epsilon > 0$ and $ n,m \geq N \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $|x_ny_n - x_my_m| < \epsilon$.  So work with the expression in the absolute value signs and write using your hint and $\Delta$ inequality, that $|x_ny_n - x_my_m| \leq |x_n(y_n - y_m)| + |y_m(x_n - x_m)| < \epsilon|x_n| + \epsilon|y_n| = \epsilon(|x_n| + |y_n|)$  I have an upper bound for $|x_n|$ and $|y_n|$, but this is in terms of $x_m$  and $y_m$ respectively.

Comment: @CAF: You’re almost there. Every Cauchy sequence is bounded, so there is an $M$ such that $|x_k|\le M$ and $|y_k|\le M$ for **all** $k$, and therefore $|x_ny_n-x_my_m|<2M\epsilon$ for all $m,n\ge N$. And since you can take $\epsilon$ to be arbitrarily small, ...

Comment: Ok I get it, thanks Brian.  One quick question:  Intuitively, why does a Cauchy sequence need be bounded?  I can see why it need be either bounded from below or from above (depending on what the case may be), but my sequence could, for example, tend to $-\infty$ as $n \rightarrow -\infty$ but as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the sequence satisfies the criterion that $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$

Comment: @CAF: If it’s Cauchy, it can’t diverge to $\pm\infty$. Let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ by Cauchy. There is an $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<1$ whenever $m,n\ge N$. Let $M=\max\{|x_k|:k\le N\}$; then $|x_n|<M+1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$: the $M$ takes care of all $x_n$ with $n\le N$, and for $n>N$ we have $|x_n-x_N|<1$, so $|x_n|<|x_N|+1\le M+1$.

Comment: Why do we have to have that $|x_n| < M + 1$ and not simply $|x_n| < M$ since $M$ is the max of all the $|x_k|$ for $k \leq N$

Comment: @CAF: To take care of the $x_n$ with $n>N$. See the last sentence of my previous comment, starting with ‘and for $n>N$’.

Comment: Makes sense now,  thank you again for your help.

Comment: @CAF: You're welcome.