# Mathematical Analysis Question: Cauchy sequences proof

Tags: cauchy-sequences

Let $(s_n)_n$  and $(a_n)_n$ be Cauchy sequences. Demonstrate that $(s_na_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: If you don't know something, look for it a bit : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Kris The editor has a question mark on yellow disk on the upper right edge, which gives you some online help on formatting.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376324/proving-that-product-of-two-cauchy-sequences-is-cauchy

Comment: You must surely have tried something. If you show us what you've tried and why it doesn't work, you'll be able to get help which actually helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen a proof that the product of convergent sequences is convergent? This is nearly identical. You can write $$|s_n a_n - s_ma_m| = |s_n a_n - s_n a_m + s_n a_m - s_m a_m| \le |s_n| |a_n - a_m| + |a_m| |s_n - s_m|.$$

Use the fact that $\{s_n\}$ and $\{a_n\}$ are Cauchy, and the fact that Cauchy sequences are bounded.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376324/proving-that-product-of-two-cauchy-sequences-is-cauchy