# If $x_n, y_n$ are Cauchy then show that $x_ny_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Assuming that both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are cauchy I need to show that $x_ny_n$ is convergent. So I know I need to have two bounds

Pick an $M \gt 0$ and choose $N_1, N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N_1$ implies $-\epsilon \lt x_n \lt \epsilon$ and $n \geq N_2$ implies $-\epsilon \lt y_n \lt \epsilon$ I am unsure of where to go from here

Comment: What is $\epsilon$?

Comment: I guess your definition of being Cauchy is wrong. Shouldn't it be $m, n \geq N_1$ implies $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$?

Comment: @BlackKnightRider: Your *title* says that you are proving $(x_n y_n)$ is *convergent*, while your *text* says that you are proving $(x_n y_n)$ is *Cauchy*. Can you please fix the title or the text so that they match?

Comment: I fixed the title

Comment: @StinkingBishop: they're the same thing, aren't they?

Comment: @TonyK: they are the same thing if the space is complete (it looks like the OP is assuming that both sequences are real valued sequences so: Yes).

Comment: @TonyK Depends ... whether you can assume that or not in the proof. That is another thing that is not specified in the question. I've just seen a question (from someone else) where you were not allowed to assume that.

Comment: Yes but The question is to prove it without using the theorem just outright states cauchy sequence is convergent. I am supposed to devlope an arguement to show it

Comment: Are they real numbers? You cannot prove it if restricting to the rationals. For example choose yn to be the constant sequence of 1, xn to be rationals converging to sqrt 2

Comment: @StinkingBishop: But if you can't assume that the space is complete, then the thing to be proved isn't true. BlackKnight, you should really say "Assume that both $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy sequences of real numbers..."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that product of two Cauchy sequences is Cauchy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376324/proving-that-product-of-two-cauchy-sequences-is-cauchy)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we may assume that $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ and $(y_n)_{n\geq1}$ are Cauchy sequences in ${\mathbb R}$. This implies that there are numbers $\alpha$, $\beta\in{\mathbb R}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\alpha, \>\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=\beta$. Now
$$x_ny_n-\alpha\beta=(x_n-\alpha)\beta+(y_n-\beta)\alpha+(x_n-\alpha)(y_n-\beta)\qquad(n\geq1)\ .$$
Given an $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that each of the three summands on the RHS here is $<{\epsilon\over3}$ for all $n>N$. Maybe you want to fill in the details for the summand $(x_n-\alpha)(y_n-\beta)$.